# IIS 7.5 / Windows Server 2008 - multiple SSL websites on single IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012, iis-8

It is possible to host multiple SSL websites on a single IP address using IIS 7.5 & Windows Server 2008? Or must one upgrade to Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible, but at least it's not supported. Microsoft clearly states that SNI is only supported on IIS 8.0 and newer.

[IIS 8.0 Server Name Indication (SNI): SSL Scalability](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability)